# Timer 3 PWM generation works but doesn't rotate the servo

Tags: c, stm32, pwm

I have been building a 6 degree of freedom industrial robot using stm32f091rc taking advantage of multiple timers to generate pwm pulses to rotate the robots' joint angles and to do forward and inverse kinematics. One problem is that even though my timer2 works for every servo motor, timer3 with the same configuration doesn't work for my second joint. I am not sure if I need to configure different files to get it working because timer2 has the same configuration and works.

```
static void MX_TIM3_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim3.Instance = TIM3;
  htim3.Init.Prescaler = 500;
  htim3.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim3.Init.Period = 1919;
  htim3.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim3.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim3, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim3, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim3, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim3);

}
```

Base init file is attached below as well as the oscilloscope signal for the pin.

```
void HAL_TIM_Base_MspInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim_base)
{
  if(htim_base->Instance==TIM2)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_TIM2_CLK_ENABLE();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_MspInit 1 */
  }
  if(htim_base->Instance==TIM3)
  {
      __HAL_RCC_TIM3_CLK_ENABLE();
  }
}
```

Post init file is attached below

```
void HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(htim->Instance==TIM2)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_MspPostInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_MspPostInit 0 */
  
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**TIM2 GPIO Configuration    
    PA0     ------> TIM2_CH1 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF2_TIM2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_MspPostInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_MspPostInit 1 */
  }
  else if(htim->Instance==TIM3)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_MspPostInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_MspPostInit 0 */

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**TIM2 GPIO Configuration
    PA1     ------> TIM3_CH1
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF1_TIM3 ;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_MspPostInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_MspPostInit 1 */
  }
  if(htim->Instance==TIM14)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM14_MspPostInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM14_MspPostInit 0 */

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**TIM14 GPIO Configuration
    PA4     ------> TIM14_CH1
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_4;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_TIM14;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM14_MspPostInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM14_MspPostInit 1 */
  }


}
```

here is my pwm output for timer3.
[image]

Comment: What is the expected output? How is the clock input to TIM3 configured?

Comment: APB peripheral clock is at 48 Mhz. I configured the Prescalar and Period to cause 50 Hz, 20 ms update event. Works for timer2 but doesn't work for timer3, I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: "16-bit (TIM3) or 32-bit (TIM2) up, down, up/down auto-reload counter" Could this be the issue?

Comment: The problem was due to insufficient current drawn from my external control board, I have solved the problem using different channel for different servos.